# How to set a Views description in Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-cli

I'm dynamically creating a view via Groovy with..

```
Jenkins.instance.getItem('my_folder').addView(new ListView('MyNewView')
```

This works great; and I then add a filter to this view via..

```
Jenkins.instance.getItem('my_folder').getView('MyNewView').setIncludeRegex('.*NewView.*'
```

Which also works wonderfully. How would I then programmatically set the views description?  I assume there's some combination I can do with

```
doSubmitDescription(...?)
```

But I haven't been able to sus it out..  Any help would be appreciated.

My current plan is to work around this by posting to `getView('MyNewView').getURL()+"/submitDescription...";`

but it should be much cleaner than that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to update the view's description, here is the line you are looking for:

```
import org.kohsuke.stapler.StaplerRequest
import org.kohsuke.stapler.StaplerResponse

Jenkins.instance.getView('MyNewView').doSubmitDescription([ getParameter: { return "My description"; }] as StaplerRequest, [ sendRedirect: { return; } ] as StaplerResponse)
```

Comment: That gives the following error: `hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap.getServletContext() is applicable for argument types: () values: []`